# Replying with JSON to an HTTP request

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to send JSON after using this request: http://localhost:8080/json_test?id=1
This is my code so far:

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)).

:- http_handler('/json_test', json_test, []).

nomeEdificio(1, "Torre dos Clérigos").
nomeEdificio(2, "Fonte dos Leões").

anoConstrucao(1, 1754).
anoConstrucao(2, 1882).

anoInauguracao(1, 1763).
anoInauguracao(2, 1884).

server(Port) :-                     
    http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

json_test(Request) :-
http_parameters(Request,
                [ id(Id, [])]
                ),
    compute_request(Id,PrologOut),
    prolog_to_json(PrologOut,JSonOut),
    reply_json(JSonOut).

compute_request(Id,PrologOut):-
    nomeEdificio(Id,N), anoConstrucao(Id,Ac), anoInauguracao(Id,Ai), % Some consulting operations
    PrologOut = json([ name=N,
        dates=json([yearConstruction=Ac, yearInauguration=Ai])
    ]).
```

But I get this error:

```
"Internal server error

goal unexpectedly failed: user:json_test([protocol(http),peer(ip(127,0,0,1)),pool(client('httpd@8080',user:http_dispatch,<stream>(00000000056CE8C0),<stream>(00000000056CCD90))),input(<stream>(00000000056CE8C0)),method(get),request_uri('/json_test?id=1'),path('/json_test'),search([id='1']),http_version(1-1),host(localhost),port(8080),user_agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'),accept([media(text/html,[],1.0,[]),media(application/'xhtml+xml',[],1.0,[]),media(application/xml,[],0.9,[]),media(_G3007/_G3008,[],0.8,[])]),accept_language('en-US,en;q=0.5'),accept_encoding('gzip, deflate'),connection('keep-alive'),upgrade_insecure_requests('1')])"
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, there's not much documentation about how to use these Prolog predicates. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Read tho documentation of [`http_parameters/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_parameters/2) for type conversion, and also check out the **`attribute_declarations/1`** option of [`http_parameters/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_parameters/3) to convert `ID` to an **integer**, so that you can query your database with it.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware about the different types. It works with `http_parameters(Request, [ id(Id, [integer]) ])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Incomplete example

When I load the code you posted, I get:

```
    catch/3: Undefined procedure: http_handler/3
```

So, I added:

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
```

## Dispatching

Next, when I load the modified example and start the server with `?- server(4040).`, and then visit `http://localhost:4040/json_test`, I get:

```
Internal server error

Undefined procedure: http_dispatch/1
```

So, I added:

```
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
```

## Parameters

Then, when I reload and revisit, I get:

```
Internal server error

Undefined procedure: http_parameters/2
```

So, I added:

```
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)).
```

## With `id`

Of course, we must supply an `id`, so I visit for example:

```
http://localhost:4040/json_test?id=x
```

Then, I get:

```
Internal server error

Undefined procedure: nomeEdificio/2
```

To debug such problems, you need to **simplify** everything as far as you can, and post simplified, **self-contained** examples with clear instructions how to run your test case.

In the above, you have *omitted*:

- essential directives which you obviously had included in your program
- essential information on how to *run* your server
- the definition of essential predicates that are used in your program.

You cannot expect others to fill such extreme omissions.

## Replying JSON

As to your actual question, your main problem is completely overshadowed by what you posted. To **reply JSON**, here is an example.

First, obtaining JSON:

```
:- use_module(library(http/json_convert)).

:- json_object
      point(x:integer, y:integer).
```

Example query:

```
?- prolog_to_json(point(10,30), JSON).
JSON = json([x=10, y=30]).
```

This *needs the directive above*, otherwise it doesn't work! This is taken **directly from the SWI-Prolog documentation**, which is a good resource to find out more about these topics.

Then, to reply with such a term:

```
?- prolog_to_json(point(10,30), JSON),
   reply_json(JSON).
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"x":10, "y":30}
...
```

So, start small: Once you have *this* running *without* HTTP server, you can plug in the *same code* into an actual dispatch.

Comment: You're right, I should've posted all the code necessary so anyone could run the program. I've edited it now.
Your answer does allow to send _facts_ over JSON, but I can't still manage to consult my knowledge base using the _id_ and then send those results.

Comment: This is only due to a mismatch between **atoms** and **integers**. It works exactly as expected if you *either* convert the *atom* `ID` to an **integer**, or rewrite your facts to use **atoms** like `'1'`, `'2'` instead of the *integers* `1`, `2`. Note the difference in using *single quotes* to denote *atoms* in this case. An elegant way to solve this is to use the type conversion of [http_parameters/2](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_parameters/2) or `attribute_declarations/1` option of [`http_parameters/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_parameters/3).